# API call function variable not set properly

Tags: python

I use this API call script to GET exchanges futures data:

```
#Exchange Open Interest
url = "https://open-api.bybt.com/api/pro/v1/futures/openInterest"

payload = {"interval":"2", "symbol":"ETH"}
headers = {
  'bybtSecret': 'secretkey'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data = payload)

print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

But I get an error message about the symbol while it's set as supposed:

> b'{"code":"40001","msg":"Required String parameter 'symbol' is not
> present","success":false}'

The not so helpful documentation:
https://bybt.gitbook.io/bybt/futures/liquidation

How to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure you're supposed to send that data in the body of the request? It looks like it may be expecting it in the query portion of the url, ie `https://open-api.bybt.com/api/pro/v1/futures/openInterest?interval=2&symbol=ETH`

Comment: if it has to send in ULR then you should use `params=` instead of `data=`

Comment: if you want resonse as bytes then get `response.content` instead of `response.text.encode('utf8')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation says `Query Parameters` which can means values in URL
and it means you have to use `params=` instead of `data=`

```
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=payload)
```

The same in `curl` needs parameters directly in URL

```
curl -H 'bybtSecret: API_KEY' 'https://open-api.bybt.com/api/pro/v1/futures/openInterest?interval=2&symbol=ETH'
```

It seems documentation has mistake(s).

**EDIT:** I sent mail to `bybt.com` that they have mistake in documentation.

---

**EDIT:**

Minimale working code with other changes

```
import requests

url = 'https://open-api.bybt.com/api/pro/v1/futures/openInterest'

payload = {
    'interval': 2,    # it can be interger 2 or string "2"
    'symbol': 'ETH',
}

headers = {
    'bybtSecret': 'API_KEY'  # 'ced..........................2A4'  # 32 chars
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload)

print('URL:', response.url)

print('Text:', response.text)

data = response.json()

print(   'Code:', data['code'])
print('Success:', data['success'])
print('Message:', data['msg'])

if data['success']:
    for item in data['data']:
        print('item:', item['symbol'], item['openInterest'])
```

Result:

```
URL: https://open-api.bybt.com/api/pro/v1/futures/openInterest?interval=2&symbol=ETH
Text: {"code":"30001","msg":"secret invalid","success":false}
   Code: 30001
Success: False
Message: secret invalid
```

---

**EDIT:**

I tested it with real `SECRET_KEY` and I got

```
URL: https://open-api.bybt.com/api/pro/v1/futures/openInterest?interval=2&symbol=ETH
Text: {"code":"0","msg":"success","data":[{"exchangeName":"All","symbol":"ETH","openInterest":5839150113.2914443890000000000,"volUsd":27990375066.873196276,"openInterestAmount":2648200.68,"h24Change":-4.5700,"rate":100,"volChangePercent":29.7900,"h1OIChangePercent":0.1500,"h4OIChangePercent":-1.8000,"avgFundingRate":-0.02241869546128241906297200,"oichangePercent":-4.5700},{"exchangeName":"Binance","symbol":"ETH","price":2204.95,"openInterest":1300428446.34257,"volUsd":11916789129.44,"openInterestAmount":589776.84,"h24Change":-0.1400,"rate":22.2700,"h1OIChangePercent":0.4200,"h4OIChangePercent":-3.3700},{"exchangeName":"Huobi","symbol":"ETH","price":2204.95,"openInterest":787226775.600000000000000000,"volUsd":5900309918.53000000,"openInterestAmount":357027.04,"h24Change":0.5300,"rate":13.4800,"h1OIChangePercent":-0.8700,"h4OIChangePercent":-3.1000},{"exchangeName":"Bitfinex","symbol":"ETH","price":2204.95,"openInterest":723293960.984549589,"volUsd":57524747.556900276,"openInterestAmount":328031.91,"h24Change":-5.5300,"rate":12.3800,"h1OIChangePercent":0.5300,"h4OIChangePercent":1.0200},{"exchangeName":"FTX","symbol":"ETH","price":2204.95,"openInterest":666545858.38536,"volUsd":2304251031.7475,"openInterestAmount":302295.23,"h24Change":-13.2200,"rate":11.4100,"h1OIChangePercent":0.1300,"h4OIChangePercent":0.5300},{"exchangeName":"Okex","symbol":"ETH","price":2204.95,"openInterest":577819527.9750000000000000000,"volUsd":4078470987.769,"openInterestAmount":262055.61,"h24Change":-0.2700,"rate":9.8900,"h1OIChangePercent":-0.0700,"h4OIChangePercent":-3.1400},{"exchangeName":"Bybit","symbol":"ETH","price":2204.95,"openInterest":548982771.2345,"volUsd":1980583480.84,"openInterestAmount":248977.42,"h24Change":-9.5200,"rate":9.4000,"h1OIChangePercent":0.0400,"h4OIChangePercent":-3.6300},{"exchangeName":"Deribit","symbol":"ETH","price":2204.95,"openInterest":537567566,"volUsd":465167313,"openInterestAmount":243800.34,"h24Change":-3.3400,"rate":9.2000,"h1OIChangePercent":-0.1700,"h4OIChangePercent":-1.0200},{"exchangeName":"CME","symbol":"ETH","price":2204.95,"openInterest":371222450,"volUsd":252820050,"openInterestAmount":168358.67,"h24Change":-7.3900,"rate":6.3500,"h1OIChangePercent":0.5600,"h4OIChangePercent":0.9600},{"exchangeName":"Bitmex","symbol":"ETH","price":2204.95,"openInterest":172609082.94946480,"volUsd":348559462.7808960,"openInterestAmount":78282.54,"h24Change":-12.2100,"rate":2.9500,"h1OIChangePercent":0.0600,"h4OIChangePercent":-0.7800},{"exchangeName":"Phemex","symbol":"ETH","price":2204.95,"openInterest":106691907.82,"volUsd":596592186.2089,"openInterestAmount":48387.45,"h24Change":-9.1000,"rate":1.8200,"h1OIChangePercent":4.4000,"h4OIChangePercent":-4.5300},{"exchangeName":"Kraken","symbol":"ETH","price":2204.95,"openInterest":46761766.0,"volUsd":89306759.0,"openInterestAmount":21207.63,"h24Change":9.5000,"rate":0.8000,"h1OIChangePercent":-0.2000,"h4OIChangePercent":1.4900}],"success":true}
   Code: 0
Success: True
Message: success

item: ETH 5841276283.273769
item: ETH 1296155383.90566
item: ETH 785092700.4644
item: ETH 723868792.828104
item: ETH 667635938.62856
item: ETH 578178981.984
item: ETH 555619872.3615
item: ETH 537213331
item: ETH 371592160.0
item: ETH 172888010.0215456
item: ETH 106231087.08
item: ETH 46800025.0
```

Comment: thank you @furas I was almost convinced that the docs didn't make sense, but I was still confused about the root cause... Your code works, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I dont have an api key so I cant get a valid response, but I do get

```
b'{"code":"30001","msg":"secret invalid","success":false}'
```

which leads me to believe it works

```
openInterest = '2'
symbol = 'ETH'

#Exchange Open Interest
url = f"https://open-api.bybt.com/api/pro/v1/futures/openInterest?interval={openInterest}&symbol={symbol}"

headers = {'bybtSecret': 'secretkey'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

Comment: you get the same result if you use `params=` instead of `data=`

Comment: Right good catch. Either work nevertheless

Comment: as for me your method is less readable but sometimes it is the only method to send some values which shouldn't be encoded to numbers like `%2D` :)